# ViewPager fragment is not working in 2nd time inside navigation drawer fragment properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have `Navigation Drawer` in which there is one fragment for the `Tab Viewer`. In tabviewer, I am using `ViewPager` which also in the `Fragment`.
The code for `ViewPager` is

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()));

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

The tabs is coming in the first click in the navigation drawer with its content but for the second time the only title of tabs is coming without its layout. Layout is not coming and swipe is also not working between different tabs?
Why its working for the first time but not for the rest?
I am attaching the images for two different click on same navigation drawer fragment.
This is first click so the layout is coming perfectly.
[image]

This in 2nd attempt to click on the same fragment but only background is coming without any layout content.

[image]

Help to get rid of this problem.

Comment: You used getChildFragmentManager() insted of ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 14):

use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager is using in TabsPagerAdapter and this getChildFragmentManager() is android.app.FragmentManager which can't be applied  in `viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());` . Its giving error saying can't applied. I make changes in  TabsPagerAdapter to make it android.app.FragmentManager but the extend class `FragmentPagerAdapter` does have `android.app.FragmentPagerAdapter. . It only support v4.app. Any solution for this to be compactible witht his v4??? or any other option to make it work. Thanks

Comment: you are not using v4.fragment that is why this issue is occuring , use v4.fragment instead of fragments

Answer (score 1):

I used getFragementManager(). So I was able to reload fragments used in tabs.
Now, I used getChildFragmentManager(). It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.

try using:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of:

```
((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
```